# Check wither internal / external DNS | ASP.NET WEB FORMS C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, webforms

I have a specific web page developed using Web forms c# that should be accessed through only an internal DNS.

the whole site can use both external and internal except for this page.

So, my question is how can I check wither the user is using internal vs external DNS in the backend c# code ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on the applicaiton level, you will need some form of authentication. Basically you can implement any kind of authentication, but to start I would recommend to look up IPrincipal. Here's a starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs

If you want to do it on the network level you might deploy this one page as a separate application, then do the checking on the IIS level.